# Create a huge flag map in C++

Tags: c++, flags

So basically, what I need is to have 28,800 values which can be accessed by an index and can all be set to true or false. Using an array of bools or integers isn't an option, because the size needs to be set during rumtime using a parameter. Using a vector is way too slow and memory intensive. I'm new to C++ and therefore don't have any idea on how to solve this, can anyone help?

EDIT: Thank you to all who commented! Like I said, Im new to C++ programming and your answers really helped me to understand the functionality behind vectors.
So, after everyone said that vector isn't slow I checked again and it turns out that my program was running so slow because of another bug I had while filling the vector. But especially midor's and Some programmer dude's answers helped me to make the program run a bit faster than before, so thanks!

Comment: why is using a vector "too slow and memory intensive" ? What is "too slow"? What is "too memory intensive"? You wont get anything less memory intensive than a `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: If a `std::vector` is too slow and memory-intensive, I'm afraid this way can't be saved. You'll need to page them.

Comment: How is vector slow? There is a space-efficient specialization for `std::vector<bool>` and there is also `std::bitset` with fixed size.

Comment: Why would a vector be slow? It's basically just a wrapper around a dynamically allocated array. Have you measured? And if you set the size (which can be done at runtime) it does a single allocation and as long as you don't attempt to resize it it's no different than dereferencing a pointer (unless you use `std::vector<bool>` which *will* be less performant since it has to calculate the bits position, but it's still fast)

Comment: "Using a vector is way too slow and memory intensive"... Have you proved it by testing/benchmarking? Have you tried the std::vector<bool> specialization?

Comment: when creating the vector, use `reserve` to allocate memory just once, then fill it.

Comment: Also, having *only* about 30000 values in a vector is not what I would call "huge". A couple of million elements perhaps, but not less than 100000. If you use `int` as type, then considering that on most systems `sizeof(int) == 4` then 30000 elements will be 120000 bytes (plus a few bytes for the pointer to the data and keeping track of the size). Not exactly memory intensive.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. There are indeed wrong ways of using a vector and even more faulty ways to measure time

Comment: Details you should know:  a) sizeof(std::vector) reports 24 bytes (in automatic memory), regardless of the number of elements.  b) The elements are stored contiguously, just like an array.  c) Expansion can be automatic, but if you know or can guess an upper limit, simply use reserve.  I have created gigabyte vectors (my desktop has 4 G of ram), and regularly use megabyte vectors.  300K is nothing.  Your question suggests premature optimization.  Being "new to C++", kudos for consulting this forum.  Now, ASK your _real_ question ... what are you trying to do?  (and leave out your speculation)

Comment: For comparison, 30,000 32-bit ints == 120 kB. Single tab with GMail in Google Chrome on Windows == 300 MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Using a vector is way too slow and memory intensive.

C++ specializes [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) so it uses only as much memory as it needs. One bit per "flag" (+ bookkeeping overhead of course).

You could only optimize that implementation if you knew its size a priori (which you don't according to your question), or if you know that the bitmap will only contain very few set bits (e.g. 1bit in a 50'000, but you'd need to measure if a more complex implementation would be worth it). For sparse bitmaps an [`std::unordered_set<std::uint32_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) that stores the set bits could be an option.

But 28'800 is a very small number, so don't waste your time on optimizations. You won't get any benefits from it.